# MySql select from list the latest connection date for each IP?

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-workbench

I have a DB that save each login to my server according to the user IP

```
2018-08-07 00:00:00, 10.1.1.1

2018-08-06 07:00:00, 10.1.1.1

2018-08-05 00:22:00, 10.1.1.1

2018-08-07 00:00:00, 10.1.1.5

2018-08-05 00:00:00, 10.1.1.5
```

and so on.....

I want to know when was the latest connection according to each IP 
so in the end I see :

```
2018-08-07 00:00:00, 10.1.1.5

2018-08-07 00:00:00, 10.1.1.1
```

I have try this :

```
SELECT IP,Time
FROM sample.connection
WHERE Time in (SELECT MAX(Time) from sample.connection GROUP BY IP);
```

but it doesn't work - I don't see the latest connection for all the IP (only some of them)

my IP is varcahr(45)

Time is Datetime

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query, you need a subquery and join:

```
SELECT sc.IP,sc.Time
FROM sample.connection sc
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT IP, MAX(Time) AS lstTime 
     FROM sample.connection 
     GROUP BY IP) t2 ON sc.Time = t2.lstTime AND sc.IP = t2.IP
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f1e51/2

```
IP          Time
--------------------------------
10.1.1.1    2018-08-07 00:00:00
10.1.1.5    2018-08-07 00:00:00
```

Comment: no - this just give the latest connection for all the IP . I want latest for each IP

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f1e51/1

```
SELECT sc.IP, sc.Time
FROM sample.connection sc
LEFT JOIN sample.connection t
ON sc.ip = t.ip
   AND sc.time<t.time
WHERE t.ip IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something. Why isn't this a simple SELECT with MAX and GROUP BY?

```
SELECT IP, MAX(Time) as Time FROM conn GROUP BY IP;
```